# Navbar is not hiding on scroll using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

I'm struggling to hide the navbar on scroll down. I know how to do it, but just because of some silly mistake I'm unable to do so, and can't figure out what the issue is.

Here's the html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="#">
                <h1>My logo</h1>
            </a>
        </div>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a class="link-button" href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-button" href="#">ARTICLES</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-button" href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-button" href="#">AUTHOR</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-button" href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="welcome">
        <h1 id="welcome-text">My Portfolio</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    </div>

    <!-- Here script for hidding navbar on scroll down  -->

    <script>
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
            let Navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
            if(window.pageYOffset > 0){
                Navbar.classList.add("navbar-scroll");
            }else{
                Navbar.classList.remove("navbar-scroll");
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the full css

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body{
    height: 100vh;
    perspective: 1px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

html{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar{
    position: sticky;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navbar #logo{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

#navbar #logo a{
    font-size: 155%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar ul{
    float: right;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

#navbar ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

/* === Here I'm changing the display property of the navbar to none to make it disappear. === */

#navbar.navbar-scroll{
    display: none;
}

.link-button{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 15px;
    font-size: 89%;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.link-button::after{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    background: #ffffff;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.link-button:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
    transition: width .3s;
}

#welcome{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#welcome::before{
    content: "";
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(#0000008e, #0000008e), url('static/bc22.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size:  cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateZ(-2px) scale(3);
}

#welcome-text{
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 26%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /* text-align: center; */
    font-size: 600%;
}


.container{
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    height: 1000px;
}
```

In the CSS I've also tried changing the background colour of the navbar on scroll (in the #navbar.navbar-scroll), but it ain't working as well. So most probably the error is in the javascript I think.

If there's a better way of hiding the navbar on scroll then that's welcomed as well.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: As an alternative, try using [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to hide and unhide navbar by removing `nav` class and adding `nav` class, or if your looking for sticky navbar use add class and add a class to the nav bar called sticky and then restyle sticky in css, then use add and remove class using waypoint script on scroll :)

Comment: My guess is that you are not scrolling the window directly. I see you have your #welcome div there and the container, maybe you need to listen to one of those scroll events? ... Try console logging inside the event to make sure you are listening to the right one

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @CoolCloud. But I'd like to keep it simple (by not using node.js, as I'm a total beginner in web-development, maybe later) by just using CSS and javascript. I know it's possible by using those two only, I've even done it before, there's just an minor error in my code that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Rishik, I think the problem is the css property `overflow:hidden` in HTML element, it causes the scroll event **doesn't** work anymore. Please remove and try again, you code is good.

Comment: Thanks @KevinLee, you're correct, that's what causing the problem. Though doing that to add a parallax effect to my background, therefore I'm gonna keep it there and add the event listener to the body for scroll, as suggested by josiaj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem lies under your HTML `overflow: hidden;`. So **when you set your HTML overflow to `hidden`, the `window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {})` will never invoke**, because `window` will never scroll at all. So **to fix this you should either remove `html{overflow: hidden;}` from your styles or add your event listener to listen to your `body` element** instead, which is not recommended.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why adding an event listener to the body is not recommended?

Comment: @Rishik there is no recommendation for that, it's based on your design. If you get to a more complex design you will probably find yourself scrolling a container div and not HTML nor the body.

Comment: @Rishik Actually this is opinion-based but in my POV the `window` is the main JavaScript object root, which is responsible for document object model so every change in the document such as `resize`, `scroll`, and so on, should happen through this object. On the other hand, `body` is responsible for the document element, so it just exists for representing the elements within it.

Answer (score 1):

From your CSS, it seems your goal is to have the body as the scroll container and not `<HTML>` itself.

Something like this should work as your JavaScript:

```
document.body.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  let Navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
  if(document.body.scrollTop > 0){
    Navbar.classList.add("navbar-scroll");
  }else{
    Navbar.classList.remove("navbar-scroll");
  }
});
```

Pretty much every tag which can have children can be scrollable if you define it in your CSS. That means you will have to listen to the right element in JS too.